# Do I put :hover in CSS and keypresses(TABs) in Javascript or do I combine them, putting both in my Javascript?

Tags: jquery, css

Do I put `:hover` in CSS and keypresses(TABs) in Javascript or do I combine them and place both in my Javascript?

I am developing my own drop-menus: styling in CSS and TABs & shift-TABs in Javascript.

When I do hover over drop-menus, drop-menu items & sub-menus, everything works .. when I press TAB or shift-TAB, everything works.

But .. if I attempt a hover **after** I begin TABbing, the code breaks .. **for example**, if I first TAB between items in a given drop-down menu, and then TAB to another MAIN menu, CSS’s :hover on the previous menu (the one I just left) no longer works. That is, the previous drop-down menu no longer "drops".

HTML:

```
<li class="drop">
    1st menu
    <ul class="aMenu">   <!-- drop menu = .aMenu -->
        <li>
            Thank you!
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
        
<li>
    2nd menu
</li>
```

CSS:

```
#menubar li:hover .aMenu {
    left: auto;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

Use `tabindex=0` for TABbing between siblings and descendants.

```
function showMenu($theMenu) {

    $theMenu.css("left", "auto");
        
    return $theMenu;   // for chaining
    
}


function hideMenu($theMenu) {

    $theMenu.css("left", "-99999px");
    
    return $theMenu;   // for chaining

}
```

**key point**: as I TAB between adjacent menus, I call `hideMenu` on the previous menu I just left.

#### Begin EDIT

I have not figured out **why** my Javascript keypress(tabindex=0) code is interfering with my CSS hover code.

In spite of that ignorance, I have figured out how to circumvent the problems I was having randomly alternating between pressing TAB(shift-TAB) and mouse hovering.

My former .CSS was:

```
li:hover .aMenu {
    left: auto;
}
```

Instead of that, I have created a new function installed via
`<body onload=" ... ">`

Well, actually 2 functions, but let's concentrate on:

```
function setupHoverOverDropMenu() {

    $("li.drop").on( {
        mouseenter: function() {
        //  alert("hover over drop-menu");
            
            if ($itsPrevDropMenu.length > 0) {
                hideMenu($itsPrevDropMenu);
                $itsPrevDropMenu = {};   // mark as hidden
            };
            
            $itsCurrDropMenu = $(this).find(".aMenu").first();
            $itsPrevDropMenu = $itsCurrDropMenu;   // for next time
            
            showMenu($itsCurrDropMenu);
        }, 
        mouseleave: function() {        
            // other Javascript code addresses on mouseleave
        }
    });   // on
    
}   // setupHoverOverDropMenu
```

I've learned a lot in the process; for example, `on mouseenter` and `on mouseleave` are inherently less bulky than using `:hover` ... so that's neat!

(the WHY I mentioned at the top is still bugging me ... but later)

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to demonstrate your issue? I'm not sure I follow

Comment: Why are you setting `$theMenu` to an empty object in `hideMenu`? It won't do anything meaningful, but if you try to chain that, it will break...

Comment: Corrected Yikes! on {} error .. will post Fiddle, but in the meantime, if and only if you wish, you're welcome to look at my interim code at [link](lovesongforever.com/testmenubar)

Comment: You are using jQuery, not Javascript.

Comment: I tried resetting a few .css every time I pressed TAB, but did not work. It's obvious I am overwriting (within my JS) some of my :hover code (within my CSS). Still working on that.

Comment: My just entered EDIT in my OP reflects my solution to my problem